# change vuex module name while importing in vue js

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

Importing vuex file with different name other than store (like "test" here). I cannot access vuex modules in Child Component like " this.$test ". How can I solve this. I need to make vuex import name other than store and accessing in child component with "this.$test" .

```
import {test} from './vuex/store.js';

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    test
});
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `store.js` has a **named** export `store`:

Just use `as`:

```
import {store as test} from './vuex/store.js';
```

If that doesn't work, your `store.js` probably only has a `default` export. In that case, just omit the curly braces and proceed as you tried:

```
import test from './vuex/store.js';
```

Comment: Not working with  " import {store as test} from './vuex/store.js';   Only works with exporting const with name ' store ' and importing with name ' { store } '. Have you check it? I recently did as per your instruction but no luck

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```js
import storeMessagerie from './store/store-messagerie'

new Vue({ 
         el: '#messagerie',
         components: { Messagerie},
         store : storeMessagerie,
         router
});
```

source : https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/#the-simplest-store

Comment: Please use select and ctrl+k OR "```" for code blocks. Not nbsp and be tags